# Memory usage optimization: High JVM memory but low execution and storage memory?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, kubernetes, pyspark, delta-lake

I'm running a spark application. After the spark application is finished, when I check the `executor` section in spark log:

[image]

First row is the driver and the second row is the executor. From my understanding, please correct me if I am wrong, the memory on-heap in executor is mainly divided by the 3 parts:

1. Reversed memory: memory reserved for system and is used to store Spark's internal objects, around 300 MB.
2. User memory: memory for the user-defined data structures / functions / metadata etc.
3. Spark memory: memory share for both storage and execution

If this is correct, I don't understand why even the peak execution and storage memory on-heap of the executor are low, also there is no big user-defined class or UDF in the application, the peak JVM memory on-heap of executor is very high in both spark log and utilization log when I check in Grafana (~6.27 GiB).

Back to my questions:

1. Is my understanding of the memory on-heap correct?
2. If my understanding is correct, why the peak JVM memory on-heap is so high?
3. How can I do the memory optimization in this case? It seems that both execution and storage memory not high.

Thank you so much for your help.

P.S: I am using Spark `3.2.1` and Delta Lake `1.2.0` on K8S deployed on EC2, 2 instances with 8 core 16 RAM, 1 instance for the driver and 1 instance for the executor. `1 core and 4g memory` is used for driver and `5 core and 8g memory` is used for executor.

Comment: How did you solve this issue ?